# Notepad++: 2 lines search and Insert 1 if missing

Tags: xml, search, notepad++

I have a large XML document on Notepad++. The document has a lot of lines like this:

`<DowntimeReason>1</DowntimeReason>
<Unscheduled>2</Unscheduled>
<Active>1</Active>`

But there are some parts where this code was copyed wrong and it looks like this:

`<DowntimeReason>1</DowntimeReason>
<Active>1</Active>`

How can I find this parts where only 2 lines where copyed and insert the missing one?????

SOS!

Comment: Are the lines allways in the same order? Is the missing line allways between the two showed? What to do if we have `<DowntimeReason>1</DowntimeReason>\n<Active>1</Active>\n<Unscheduled>2</Unscheduled>`? Are the values allways the same or are they any numbers or any characters? Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58947146/edit) and add more lines and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

In the Search Mode area, select "Regular expression" in Find.

Find what:

```
<DowntimeReason>1<\/DowntimeReason>\r\n<Active>1<\/Active>
```

Replace with:

```
<DowntimeReason>1<\/DowntimeReason>\r\n<Unscheduled>2<\/Unscheduled>\r\n<Active>1<\/Active>
```